# How to get a response after calling an external Web Service that's using SOAP. - Dynamics AX 2012 R3

Tags: web-services, soap, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm consuming an external Web Service in Dynamics AX 2012 using a Service Reference I created in Visual Studio, the Visual Studio .dll file has been deployed to my AX AOT.  This gives me references within AX to call the relevant services from the Web Service.

I have created a class to call the web service to which i pass data from several tables, build a 'body' of data that the Web Service requires and then i send this body of data using the relevant Request service from the web service.

However, when the data is sent i am struggling to understand how i get a response back from the server if all was sent OK or if there was an error.  At the moment the data is sent fine but don't get any response back.

The Web Service is a SOAP envelope service and has reference values to pass the data to, for example,

`<iItemNumber>Int</iItemNumber>
<sItemDescription>String</sItemDescription>`

Is there anyway i can get a response back in AX to then know if all was received OK from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Response object should be the result of calling a web service menthod

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/walkthrough-calling-an-external-web-service-from-x